# MVC template variables, did I exceed the range?

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, range, templating

I'm doing some templating in PHP where I search for `{tmp_vars}` and replace them with HTML. I have one variable called `{content}`, which is essentially the current page I want to display.

What I noticed is that when `{content}` -- which is essentially my views/page.php inside this variable -- gets too much content (specifically above 4095 characters including HTML tags, text, whitespace, comments, everything in that file), my page kind of breaks. I suddenly see an unwanted `<style>…</style>` in my head, and my title and stylesheets have jumped into the body.

When I remove just a few characters in my HTML content to get below 4096 characters, everything snaps back into place.

Does this have to do with how many bytes I'm allowed to use in a string variable or something? I would expect string to have a higher range than only 4095 bytes max.

---

Example on how `{content}` is used in my layouts/defaut.php:

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- Title and links to stylesheets -->
</head>
<body>
{content}<!-- Insert views/page.php here -->
</body>
</html>
```

And in my controller.php:

```php
public $vars = [];

private function filterVars ($content)
    foreach ($this->vars as $key => $value)
        if (!is_array($value))
            $content = str_replace("{" . $key . "}", $value, $content);
    
    return $content;
}

public function render ($filename) {
    extract($this->vars);
    ob_start();
    
    require(ROOT . "Views/" . ucfirst(str_replace("Controller", "", get_class($this))) . "/" . $filename . ".php");
    
    $layout = ob_get_clean();
    $layout = $this->filterVars($layout);
    $this->set("content", $layout);
}
```

---

When `{content}` (so `$vars["content"]`) exceeds 4095 characters (I assume that there is a 4096th character which is the `\0` character), my title and stylesheets jump out of the head and into the body, while in the head the following `<style>…</style>` appears:

```html
<style>._3emE9--dark-theme .-S-tR--ff-downloader{background:rgba(30,30,30,.93);border:1px solid rgba(82,82,82,.54);box-shadow:0 4px 7px rgba(30,30,30,.55);color:#fff}._3emE9--dark-theme .-S-tR--ff-downloader ._6_Mtt--header ._2VdJW--minimize-btn{background:#3d4b52}._3emE9--dark-theme .-S-tR--ff-downloader ._6_Mtt--header ._2VdJW--minimize-btn:hover{background:#131415}._3emE9--dark-theme .-S-tR--ff-downloader ._10vpG--footer{background:rgba(30,30,30,.93)}._2mDEx--white-theme .-S-tR--ff-downloader{background:#fff;border:1px solid rgba(82,82,82,.54);box-shadow:0 4px 7px rgba(30,30,30,.55);color:#314c75}._2mDEx--white-theme .-S-tR--ff-downloader ._6_Mtt--header{font-weight:700}._2mDEx--white-theme .-S-tR--ff-downloader ._2dFLA--container ._2bWNS--notice{border:0;color:rgba(0,0,0,.88)}._2mDEx--white-theme .-S-tR--ff-downloader ._10vpG--footer{background:#fff}.-S-tR--ff-downloader{display:block;overflow:hidden;position:fixed;bottom:20px;right:7.1%;width:330px;height:180px;background:rgba(30,30,30,.93);border-radius:2px;color:#fff;z-index:99999999;border:1px solid rgba(82,82,82,.54);box-shadow:0 4px 7px rgba(30,30,30,.55);transition:.5s}.-S-tR--ff-downloader._3M7UQ--minimize{height:62px}.-S-tR--ff-downloader._3M7UQ--minimize .nxuu4--file-info,.-S-tR--ff-downloader._3M7UQ--minimize ._6_Mtt--header{display:none}.-S-tR--ff-downloader ._6_Mtt--header{padding:10px;font-size:17px;font-family:sans-serif}.-S-tR--ff-downloader ._6_Mtt--header ._2VdJW--minimize-btn{float:right;background:#f1ecec;height:20px;width:20px;text-align:center;padding:2px;margin-top:-10px;cursor:pointer}.-S-tR--ff-downloader ._6_Mtt--header ._2VdJW--minimize-btn:hover{background:#e2dede}.-S-tR--ff-downloader ._13XQ2--error{color:red;padding:10px;font-size:12px;line-height:19px}.-S-tR--ff-downloader ._2dFLA--container{position:relative;height:100%}.-S-tR--ff-downloader ._2dFLA--container .nxuu4--file-info{padding:6px 15px 0;font-family:sans-serif}.-S-tR--ff-downloader ._2dFLA--container .nxuu4--file-info div{margin-bottom:5px;width:100%;overflow:hidden}.-S-tR--ff-downloader ._2dFLA--container ._2bWNS--notice{margin-top:21px;font-size:11px}.-S-tR--ff-downloader ._10vpG--footer{width:100%;bottom:0;position:absolute;font-weight:700}.-S-tR--ff-downloader ._10vpG--footer ._2V73d--loader{animation:n0BD1--rotation 3.5s linear forwards;position:absolute;top:-120px;left:calc(50% - 35px);border-radius:50%;border:5px solid #fff;border-top-color:#a29bfe;height:70px;width:70px;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center}.-S-tR--ff-downloader ._10vpG--footer ._24wjw--loading-bar{width:100%;height:18px;background:#dfe6e9;border-radius:5px}.-S-tR--ff-downloader ._10vpG--footer ._24wjw--loading-bar ._1FVu9--progress-bar{height:100%;background:#8bc34a;border-radius:5px}.-S-tR--ff-downloader ._10vpG--footer ._2KztS--status{margin-top:10px}.-S-tR--ff-downloader ._10vpG--footer ._2KztS--status ._1XilH--state{float:left;font-size:.9em;letter-spacing:1pt;text-transform:uppercase;width:100px;height:20px;position:relative}.-S-tR--ff-downloader ._10vpG--footer ._2KztS--status ._1jiaj--percentage{float:right}</style>
```

I have never written any of the above CSS. I have no idea where it's coming from.

---

Minimal, Reproducible Example for the odd CSS: (yes, it is that short)

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Odd CSS will appear below title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $contentThatWorks = "This is a string...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    with a lot of whitespace";
    $contentThatDoesNotWork = "This is a string...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    with a lot of whitespace";

    echo $contentThatWorks;
    echo $contentThatDoesNotWork;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us the code you're having issues with. It's hard to help out with code issues without seeing anything. Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info.

Comment: I showed the code I'm having issues with. PHP replaces `{content}` with a string that is larger than 4095 characters. All I'm asking is whether this is the maximum range of the string datatype. If you require how I'm setting the `$content` variable in PHP, stand by.

Comment: You're only showing us some HTML markup. I'm asking about the actual "search and replace" code. You also say _"I suddenly see an unwanted <style>…</style> in my head"_ without any more explanation about that. What does it contain? Please click on the link in my first comment about creating a MRE and update your question with _all_ relevant code.

Comment: How about now? Everything works fine, normally. Only when I highlight my entire file and see a number of characters greater than 4095 does this happen. 4096 bytes = 32.768 bits. I swear I've seen this number before…

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It turns out that the weird `<style>…</style>` is there in the browser, no matter what, on every single website that I go to. So that's not me.

Comment: Solved the issue! -- I will post my solution within a day or so. It has to do with the fact that the default memory capacity of output buffers (i.e. ob_start(); echo $something; $content = ob_get_clean();) only can store up to 4MB at one time. I managed to change this range, and my site runs fine now. -- Again, I'll post a detailed answer for other people very soon!